# What is a clean way to map a template without to know the total items

Tags: python, templates

In this example I have 2 items in the data list and want parse template with each items and generate a result:

```py
template = [  {"id": "<ID>", "interfaces": [{"port": "<PORT>", "description": "<NAME>"}]} ]

data = [  {'id': '1234', 'port': 'ETH0', "description": "MyDescName"},
          {'id': '4567', 'port': 'ETH1', "description": "MyDescName-2"} ]

result  = [  {"id": "1234", "interfaces": [{"port": "ETH0", "description": "MyDescName"}]},
             {"id": "4567", "interfaces": [{"port": "ETH1", "description": "MyDescName-2"}] ]
```

Comment: Can you give a bit more context? Do you receive the template in this format or do you already know it beforehand? Do you simply want to know how to convert data to have elements that are in the template format, or do you need to do this for many different templates?

Comment: Yes I receive the template in this format. I need to convert data to have elements that are in the template format.

Comment: Is the template dynamic? And is there any constraint for templates you accept?

Comment: The template is static,  and there is no constraint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = [  
        {'id': '1234', 'port': 'ETH0', "description": "MyDescName"},
        {'id': '4567', 'port': 'ETH1', "description": "MyDescName-2"},
       ]
                 
result = []

for element in data:
  result.append({"id": element["id"], "interfaces": [{"port": element["port"], "description": element["description"]}]})

print(result)
```

This one liner works too.

```
result2 = list(map(lambda element: {"id": element["id"], "interfaces": [{"port": element["port"], "description": element["description"]}]}, data))
```

Gives output

```
[
 {'id': '1234', 'interfaces': [{'port': 'ETH0', 'description': 'MyDescName'}]}, 
 {'id': '4567', 'interfaces': [{'port': 'ETH1', 'description': 'MyDescName-2'}]}
]
```

Comment: res.append = result.append

Comment: Oops! fixed the typo.